# #Define Entire function call with arguments?

Tags: c, function, call, c-preprocessor

I have a program that I am running on two different compilers, and each compiler has a different file handling library.  For example on library requires:

```
fwrite(buffer,size,elements,file)
```

While the other is:

```
f_write(file,buffer,size,elements)
```

is there anyway I could use a global `#define` in my main header file inside of a `#ifdef` statement that would allow me to seamlessly transition between compilers?

Comment: `f_write` lol where's that from then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure:

```
#ifdef STUPID_COMPILER
# define fwrite(ptr, size, nitems, stream) f_write(stream, ptr, size, nitems)
#endif
```

Then just use `fwrite()` in your code -- no wrapper function needed. The preprocessor will translate it to an `f_write()` call if you're using the compiler/library that requires that.

Comment: Perhaps the "other" compiler isn't providing a standard implementation, thus the name difference?  Not necessarily stupid, but obviously different?  BTW, I think the answer you provided is the "right" way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a new function:

```
size_t my_fwrite(...)
{
#ifdef REAL_FWRITE
    return fwrite(buffer,size,elements,file);
#elif  F_WRITE
    return f_write(file,buffer,size,elements);
#else
    #error "No fwrite"      
#endif
}
```

---

What kind of implementation doesn't provide `fwrite` but has `f_write` ?

Comment: Yup, this is the best approach, as it encapsulates the #define in one place.

Comment: I've seen this for FAT file system implementations.  The user of this code should provide some glue macros to translate the standard call to the specific file system implementation.  This was for an embedded system where there was no file system implementation provided in the default compiler implementation.

Comment: @cnicutar, no problem. 1 down, Inf - 1 to go, then we're even :-)